# Books or other sources for natural units, Planck units, dimensional analysis etc. for someone with only high-school physics knowledge

Tags: resource-recommendations, units, dimensional-analysis, absolute-units

I'd like to know more about [natural units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units), [Planck units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units), [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis), etc., and things like how units are "created" by man or by the universe, universal constants and where they come from. Things like that, but I can't find any books on the subject. Does anyone know any books on the subject that don't require university level physics and/or math?

Comment: I strongly recommend that you learn axiomatic linear algebra first. After that, a lot of things are much easier to see and formalise (and it’s pretty useful for almost everything you can do with those units in other respects).

Comment: Units are simply comparisons against a physical "normal".  All you have to learn is that physics is the description of complex natural processes by means of simple natural processes. The "most simple such processes" are our base units for distance, time etc.. Everything else is "just" a smart combination of these. Learning about units without learning about physics is therefor pretty useless.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a good start with "[Order of Magnitude Physics](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/sanjoy/oom/book-letter.pdf)" by Goldreich, Mahajan, & Phinney (Cambridge link). The subtitle tells everything about the method: "Understanding the World with Dimensional Analysis, Educated Guesswork, and White Lies". Examples are given in abundance, from problems of scale and Newtonian mechanics, to material properties and waves.
Not sure if it's always at only high school level, but there are plenty examples that are. And the style is extra-down-to-earth-friendly.